# How can I dial a calling card number and enter a PIN programmatically within an iOS application?

Tags: iphone, ios, cocoa-touch

I'm building an iOS app which will dial a calling card access number and then the destination number (PIN not required because the service provider has Caller ID authentication). Everything works, but when I dial a number it shows 1231223344,,,,,11112222 in the dialer and recent calls.

Is it possible to show only 1231223344? I don't want to show any pause (,) or subsequent dialed numbers. This is the code I'm using so far:

```
-(IBAction)dialButtonPressed:(UIButton *)numberButton
{
    phoneNumberLabel.text = phoneNumberString;

    NSString *numberToDial = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"tel:1231223344,,,,,%@", phoneNumberString];
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:numberToDial]];

    NSLog(@"Dialing Phone Number");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

While it isn't directly possible to dial one number but show another number in the dial history, there is somewhat of a workaround:

Create a contact in the address book with a phone number of 1231223344,,,,,11112222 and a first name of 1231223344. If there is a contact matching a number in the address book, the call history will show the name (in this case the number without the calling card) and not the number.